# laravel 5.4 yajra datatable cant query table by url id says Missing required parameters

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I want to query table by url id from yajra datatable but I can't query missing parameter.

**controller**

```
public function getpostshow($id,request $request)
{   
   $medrep = Medrep::find($id);
   $req = $request->segment(2);
    $users = DB::table('itinerarys')
    ->select('doctors.*','medreps.*','itinerarys.*')
    ->join('doctors', 'itinerarys.doctor', '=', 'doctors.doctor_id')
    ->join('medreps', 'itinerarys.medrep', '=', 'medreps.medrep_id')
    ->where('itinerarys.medrep', '=', $req);
    return Datatables::of($users)
    ->editColumn('EmployeeLastName', '{!! str_limit($EmployeeLastName, 60) !!}')
    ->editColumn('CustomerCode', '{!! str_limit($CustomerCode, 60) !!}')
    ->editColumn('CustomerLastName', '{!! str_limit($CustomerLastName, 60) !!}')

    ->make(true);
}
```

**route**

```
Route::get('medrep/{id}/getpostshow', 
['as'=>'medrep.getpostshow','uses'=>'MedrepController@getpostshow']);
```

Comment: Please show your form method for [Route: medrep.getpostshow] in blade file

Comment: you have to write like this `"ajax": "{{ route('medrep.getposts', ["id"=>$whateverID]) }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a value when you call route

`{{ route('medrep.getposts', ['id' => 1]) }}`

Comment: "ajax": "{{ route('medrep.getpostshow', ['id' => $medrep]) }}"       i do it man but it says undefind variable medrep

Comment: hey man its working but when i go to /medrep it says undefined  variable medrep

Comment: ErrorException in 3ebfed88e002be05c605d0dcedcdf15eb94426a2.php line 207:
Undefined variable: medrep (View: C:\wamp\www\emcp.dm\resources\views\layouts\app-template.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\emcp.dm\resources\views\layouts\app-template.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\emcp.dm\resources\views\layouts\app-template.blade.php)

Comment: You might not have value in `$medrep` variable or may be your is not defined on view or controller

Comment: how can i defined the $medrep is defined in controller because its working but its not defined in view

Comment: hey man thank u i solved it by arranging my views now works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

you should use $id parameter after Request like this:

```
public function getpostshow(Request $request,$id)
```

and Request parameter is `Request $request` not `request $request`

Comment: i do that but nothing happens it say Missing required parameters for [Route: medrep.getpostshow] [URI: medrep/{id}/getpostshow]. (View: C:\wamp\www\emcp.dm\resources\views\layouts\app-template.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\emcp.dm\resources\views\layouts\app-template.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\emcp.dm\resources\views\layouts\app-template.blade.php)

Comment: "ajax": "{{ route('medrep.getposts') }}", this is my table route

Comment: Laravel by default assumes the first parameter is a request object, so it is important to get the order correct.

Comment: Route::get('medrep/{id}', 
['as'=>'medrep.getpostshow','uses'=>'MedrepController@getpostshow']);  try this remove getpostshow

Comment: That route requires $id medrep/{id}/getpostshow  so you can't use the route helper in this case. concat the url together with the $id in the middle

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: medrep.getpostshow] [URI: medrep/{id}]. (View: C:\wamp\www\emcp.dm\resources\views\layouts\app-template.blade.php)                        same error occured the getpostshow is hidden in the url because that is the data of my table

Comment: You have to pass a value when you call route.

`{{ route('medrep.getposts', ['id' => $whateverID]) }}`

Comment: hey pankaj i {{ route('medrep.getposts', ['id' => $whateverID])  write this in my ajax table but sa missing variable  $whateverID

Comment: {{ route('medrep.getposts', ['id' => $whateverID])  it is working now my only problem is when i go to route /medrep it say undefined variable $whateverI

Comment: @SebastianMendoza `$whateverID` just an example you have to pass your variable name of any value